# Sort vector of class

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

Before I get my fair share of "this is a duplicate of link-to-thread" replies, I'd like to say that I've implemented both what I have been reading on StackOverflow and on the CPlusPlus website. The problem is that my vector won't sort. I must be missing something in the implementation. Maybe incorrect use of references etc.

Here goes: I have two classes - DETargetParam and a wrapper class named DETargetParamVector that includes an STL vector of type DETargetParam. My objective is to sort the std::vector in ascending order using the fitness member variable of DETargetParam. I've tried to do that by overloading the less than operator in the DETargetParam class and returning a boolean result.

This, however, does not sort. Everything compiles and executes perfectly, but there's no sort. I really hope someone here can help me.

This is the source code for DETargetParam:

```
#ifndef _DE_TARGET_PARAM_H_DP_
#define _DE_TARGET_PARAM_H_DP_

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class DETargetParam {
 private:
  /** The array of N parameters in type T */
  T param[N];
  long double fitness;
  long double probability;
  long double probabilityInterval;

 public:
  /**
   * @brief Default constructor.
   *
   * Nada!
   */
  DETargetParam() {
    /* NULL */
  }

  long double getFitness() {
    return fitness;
  }

  void setFitness(long double x) {
    fitness = x;
  }

  long double getProbability() {
    return probability;
  }

  void setProbability(long double x) {
    probability = x;
  }

  long double getProbabilityInterval() {
    return probabilityInterval;
  }

  void setProbabilityInterval(long double x) {
    probabilityInterval = x;
  }

  bool operator<(const DETargetParam& rhs) const {
    return (fitness < rhs.fitness);
  }

  T& operator[](unsigned int i) {
    return param[i];
  }
};

#endif // _DE_TARGET_PARAM_H_DP_
```

and the DETargetParamVector wrapper class:

```
#ifndef _DE_TARGET_PARAM_VECTOR_H_DP_
#define _DE_TARGET_PARAM_VECTOR_H_DP_

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

#include "DETargetParam.h"

template <typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int NP>
class DETargetParamVector {
 private:
  /** This is a STL vector holding the parameters */
  std::vector< DETargetParam<T, N> > vec;

 public:
  /**
   * @brief Default constructor
   *
   * Move along... nothing to see here.
   */
  DETargetParamVector() {
    vec.reserve(NP);
  }

  void SortAndCalculate() {
    SortVector();
    PrintSorted();
  }

  void SortVector() {
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  }

  void PrintSorted() {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NP; ++i) {
      fprintf(stdout, "%.12Lf, %.12Lf, %.12Lf\n", vec[i].getFitness(), vec[i].getProbability(), vec[i].getProbabilityInterval());
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "\n");

    fflush(stdout);
  }

  DETargetParam<T, N>& operator[](unsigned int i) {
    return vec[i];
  }
};

#endif // _DE_TARGET_PARAM_VECTOR_H_DP_
```

and the main function details:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

#include "DETargetParamVector.h"

const unsigned int N = 10;
const unsigned int NP = 10;

int main() {
  srand(time(0));

  DETargetParamVector<long double, N, NP> targetVector;

  // For each member of the population.
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NP; ++i) {
    targetVector[i].setFitness(static_cast<long double>(rand()));
  }

  targetVector.SortAndCalculate();

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see a `SortVector` method, but I don't see you calling it anywhere.

Comment: I initialize a DETargetParamVector variable and call SortAndCalculate() in a main method.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually place anything into the vector, so there is nothing to sort. If you add that, the code should work. If not, please create a complete compilable sample that has the issue you describe.

Comment: Okay, I will add what you've requested. I can assure you though that the vector is populated with data because I can see it during the PrintVectors() stage. They're just not sorted.

Comment: I don't think your `main` will compile. What type is `T` there? More generally, please present the smallest complete, compileable program that demonstrates your problem. For more information on this debugging technique, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I honestly apologise for the inconvenience, but this is a big project (lines of code in the thousands). The code was working perfectly and I was asked to modify it in order to be able to sort the vector using the fitness variable. The only issue is that std::sort does not sort the vector. The software still compiles and executes perfectly.

Comment: P.s. `main` invokes `DETargetParamVector<>::operator[]()`, which isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: @sudosensei - We believe you that your project compiles. But we don't have access to (AND DON'T WANT ACCESS TO) your project. The best way that we can help you is for us to examine an analog of your project. Years of experience have shown that hand-picked fragments of your project are a poor analog, but an other-wise working trivial program can be a good analog.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've added the missing pieces and simplified the main method. Is something else required?

Comment: The key points are "working" and "trivial" (which would be better "minimal") - this means you can copy the code, paste it into an editor, compile it, and see the problem that you have, without code that is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your vector does get sorted. The issue is that your vector is empty, and all you do is write and read outside of the vector.

```
  /**
   * @brief Default constructor
   *
   * Move along... nothing to see here.
   */
  DETargetParamVector() {
    vec.reserve(NP);
  }
```

The comment is quite ironic, because here is your error. `vec.reserve(NP)` does not change the size of the vector, it just does something to save work in the future. You need to replace reserve with resize, or even better just initialize it from the start:

```
  /**
   * @brief Default constructor
   *
   * Move along... nothing to see here.
   */
  DETargetParamVector() : vec(NP) {
  }
```

On a side node, this:

```
int N = 10;
int NP = 10 * N;

int main() {
  DETargetParamVector<long double, N, NP> targetVector;
```

is illegal, because you have non-const ints as template arguments. You need to replace `int N` with `int const N` (likewise for NP).

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a somewhat simplified version of your code, that at least works to generate and sort some objects. I've also (at least IMO) fixed a few places that your design struck me as somewhat problematic (though the result still falls well short of perfect, at least IMO).

de_target_param.h:

```
#ifndef _DE_TARGET_PARAM_H_DP_
#define _DE_TARGET_PARAM_H_DP_

#include <iostream>

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class DETargetParam {
private:
    /** The array of N parameters in type T */
    //  T param[N];
    long double fitness;
    //  long double probability;
    //  long double probabilityInterval;

public:
    DETargetParam(long double f) : fitness(f) { }
    /*
    long double getFitness() {
    return fitness;
    }

    void setFitness(long double x) {
    fitness = x;
    }

    long double getProbability() {
    return probability;
    }

    void setProbability(long double x) {
    probability = x;
    }

    long double getProbabilityInterval() {
    return probabilityInterval;
    }

    void setProbabilityInterval(long double x) {
    probabilityInterval = x;
    }
    */
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, DETargetParam const &d) { 
        return os << d.fitness;
    }

    bool operator<(const DETargetParam& rhs) const {
        return (fitness < rhs.fitness);
    }
};

#endif // _DE_TARGET_PARAM_H_DP_
```

de_target_param_vector.h:

```
#include "de_target_param.h"

#ifndef _DE_TARGET_PARAM_VECTOR_H_DP_
#define _DE_TARGET_PARAM_VECTOR_H_DP_

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, unsigned int N, unsigned int NP>
class DETargetParamVector {
    std::vector< DETargetParam<T, N> > vec;
public:
    void push(DETargetParam<T, N> const &d) {
        vec.push_back(d);
    }

    void SortAndCalculate() {
        SortVector();
        std::cout << *this;
    }

    void SortVector() {
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, DETargetParamVector const &d) {
        std::copy(d.vec.begin(), d.vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<DETargetParam<T, N> >(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};

#endif // _DE_TARGET_PARAM_VECTOR_H_DP_
```

And, I've written a small `main` that creates, sorts, and prints, (in sorted order) some objects:

```
#include "de_target_param_vector.h"

int main() {

    DETargetParamVector<int, 1, 5> params;

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
        params.push(rand());

    params.SortAndCalculate();
    return 0;
}
```

Based on how you designed your `DETargetParam` class, I think a bit of Googling for "pseudo object oriented" or something similar should turn up some useful, relevant reading. A great deal of your code seems (at least to me) to exemplify the genre.